# Pivot table reindexing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having a dataframe as below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name1':['A','Q','A','B','B','C','C','C','E','E','E'],
                    'Name2':['B','C','D','C','D','D','A','B','A','B','C'],'Marks2':[10,20,6,50, 88,23,140,9,60,65,70]})
df1

#created a new frame
new=df1.loc[(df1['Marks2'] <= 50)]
new

#created a pivot table
temp=new.pivot_table(index="Name1", columns="Name2", values="Marks2")
temp
```

I tried to re-index the pivot table.

```
new_value=['E']
order = new_value+list(temp.index.difference(new_value))
matrix=temp.reindex(index=order, columns=order)
matrix
```

But the values related to 'E' is not present in pivot table. dataframe df1 contains values related with E. I need to add the value related to E in the pivot_table

Expected output:

[image: img]

Comment: kindly add the expected output dataframe

Comment: I don't quite get the expected result. May you manually write the expected table and add it above or clarify it a bit more?

Comment: you filtered them out when you created `new` df , what would you expect

Comment: @sammywemmy, can you check that question now?

Comment: @MagnusO_O,updated the question,can you check that?

Comment: @eshirvana,can you check the question now?

Comment: As eshirvana mentioned, just don't remove the 'E's. So skip the `new=df1.loc[(df1['Marks2'] <= 50)]` part.

Comment: I just needed a dataframe with marks2 is less than 50.but after that i need to add the value E at the begining

Comment: Your expected output does have marks > 50 included. You may want to re-think the problem or the example data you've posted.

Comment: But after that, I need to add new value E at the begining of pivot_table and need to add the values related to E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments my understanding of the intended result:

```
    E     A     B     C     D
E NaN  60.0  65.0  70.0   NaN
A NaN   NaN  10.0   NaN   6.0
C NaN   NaN   9.0   NaN  23.0
Q NaN   NaN   NaN  20.0   NaN
```

**Code:**
Activate the inlcuded `#print()` statements to see what the steps do.
Especially at the header 'formatting' in the end you may adapt acc. your needs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name1':['A','Q','A','B','B','C','C','C','E','E','E'],
                    'Name2':['B','C','D','C','D','D','A','B','A','B','C'],
                    'Marks2':[10,20,6,50, 88,23,140,9,60,65,70]})
```

```
df1['Marks2'] = np.where( (df1['Marks2'] >= 50) & (df1['Name1'] != 'E'), 
                         np.nan, df1['Marks2'])
#print(df1)
```

```
temp=df1.pivot_table(index="Name1", columns="Name2", values="Marks2")
#print(temp)
```

```
name1_to_move = 'E'

# build new index with name1_to_move at the start (top in df idx)
idx=temp.index.tolist() 
idx.pop(idx.index(name1_to_move))
idx.insert(0, name1_to_move)
# moving the row to top by reindex
temp=temp.reindex(idx)
#print(temp)
```

```
temp.insert(loc=0, column=name1_to_move, value=np.nan)
#print(temp)
```

```
temp.index.name = None
#print(temp)
```

```
temp = temp.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print(temp)
```